# How to plot some months in years of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
a = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Leonardo\Desktop\TRABALHO\dadosboias\MARINHA_TRATADO\Cabo Frio\boia_1\cabofrio.csv', na_values=['-9999.0'])
a.index = pd.to_datetime(a[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute']])
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

The output is something like this:

```
index               wspd                wdir    gust            hs
2009-06-24 15:21:00 1.4669884357700003  9.0     2.03121475722   nan
2009-06-24 16:21:00 1.4669884357700003  34.0    2.03121475722   nan
2009-06-24 17:21:00 0.677071585741      127.0   1.35414317148   nan
2009-06-24 18:21:00 0.22569052858000002 146.0   0.902762114322  nan
...                 ...                 ...     ...
2013-02-10 17:21:00 nan                 nan     nan             nan
```

And doing a simple plotting with `plt.plot(a.hs, 'r.')` the output is this:

[image]

As can be seeable the dataframe has a lot of missing data in "hs" column. The main objective is to plot just the periods with data. In the image you can see that 2012-03 to 2013-3 have a lot of good data of "hs", so the objective is to plot this period and get something like this:

[image]

I Would be thankful if someone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select the relevant range, e.g.

```
a.loc['2012-03-01':'2013-03-01', 'hs'].plot()
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Just one more thing, if i want to READ (when i'm reading the file) just this period instead of all dataframe, how do I do?

Comment: Either read the whole dataframe and then filter, or create a custom reader to filter rows that are not in your range.